# Google.Analytics. Make a report on url parameters values

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to make a report, where lines of the table will be different url parameter values and other columns - say ecommerce (transactions, CR)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no out of the box report.

To do that you would need to:

- create custom dimensions in the property settings (you only have 20). Let's say you name them imaginatively parameter1 - parameter20
- user filters to map the query parameter (lets say param1-param20) to the custom dimension.
- create a custom report for your custom dimensions

Go to filters, custom, advanced. Set Field A First field Request URI. In the Extract A field you enter (for a GET parameter "param1") the expression param1=([^&.]*). This stores the value for param1 in a variable called $A1. Leave Field B and Extract B empty.

In "Output to" select the name of your custom dimension, in this case "parameter1".  In Constructor enter $A1. This will map the value extracted from the parameter to your custom dimension.

Other options: Field A required "Yes", Field B required "No", Override Output Field "Yes", case sensitive "No".

Now wait a while until data has been collected. Then go to "customization", create a new custom report, select parameter1 (or any other of your custom dimensions) as dimension and add metrics at your gusto. The report will only show data for pageview where the dimension has been set.

You would probably create your custom dimensions at hit level (unless you are only interested in the last value in a user session), so combining them with conversion metrics like transactions might produce not particulary valid results.

If you have more than 20 different url parameters you want to capture you are out of luck.

(Btw. I'm not actually sure this is a on-topic question, but the answer has an regular expression in it so it might count. Still reporting questions are probably better suited for webmasters.stackexchange.org).